# How can I know which user my .NET application is running on the web server?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, web-applications, web

We are developing a mini social networking web application. It has to get some [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) data from another web application. Strangly, when we run the code on our developer machine everything is fine and we get the JSON data. But when the same application is deployed on a web server, we get an error saying

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

Please note: our login mode is Windows authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
</authentication>
```

Comment: Sounds more like a networking issue. Perhaps your firewall is blocking incoming traffic.

Comment: IIS App Pools can run as a user.  The default identity is NETWORKSERVICE, which probably does not have rights to access the resource you're trying to use.  Typically NETWORKSERVICE is a user account on the machine that the web server runs on, and therefore has no actual identity in the domain.  As one solution, you can change the identity that the AppPool runs under.  The other solution is to allow for anonymous requests of the JSON app.

Comment: On IIS7 that's ApplicationPoolIdentity. You can use impersonation to run selected pieces of your code as the user of your choice.

Comment: thanks Maurice Reeves, your way was correct. Now we chaged from "NetworkService" to "LocalSystem" and all started workig.

Comment: LocalSystem is a high privilege account - it includes a token for the builtin/administrators group. You shouldn't run your service like that as it increases the damage that an attacker can do.

Comment: Also NetworkService does have an identity on the domain. It acts like a member of the Everyone and AuthenticatedUsers groups. What you have done is make your web site run as an administrator.

Comment: Why do you think that this error is due to login issue?

Answer (score 0):

It might take a little trial and error, but in Visual Studio, if you open menu *Debug* -> *Attach to Process*, and then select your webserver in the Qualifier box, you should see a listing of all the running processes along with information, like user name and [PID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier).

If you either know the PID or manually find out which process is your application, you should be able to determine which username is being used.